# Cколько памяти занимает массив? С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Имеется код:

```
int main() {
    char* buf = new char[16];
    delete[] buf;
    return 0;
}
```

Часть памяти по адресу созданного массива выглядит так:
[image: Матрица байтов]
Зеленым я выделил сами данные в массиве, желтым те байты, назначение которых мне неизвестно. Важно заметить, что желтые всегда создаются именно такими, какими они тут указаны вне зависимости от размера массива и его адреса.

При выполнении **delete[] buf** изменяются следующие байты:
[image: Матрица байтов]

На всякий случай, я так же прикреплю снимок памяти до удаления массива со всеми затронутыми байтами (для удобного сопоставления)
[image: Матрица байтов]

**Вопрос**: почему при выполнении **delete[] buf** изменяется значительно больше байтов, чем массив должен занимать? Известно ли, что именно за данные хранятся в дополнительном пространстве?

Сборка выполняется под windows 10 x86

Comment: Ну мало ли какую служебную информацию хранит менеджер памяти?...

Comment: Всё зависит от операционной системы, конкретной версии компилятора и архитектуры памяти компьютера. Полного ответа быть не может.

Comment: Ммм... Это удручает... Но все таки, я хотя бы получаю подсказки, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Простите за нескромный вопрос, а зачем вам это надо? Если просто интереса ради, то исходники стандартной библиотеки C/C++ открыты - изучите, как работает `malloc()` (вызывается внутри `new()`), возможно найдёте ответы на вопросы.